# ios screen show like this when using local_auth but it's fine on android Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I use local auth package **Flutter**, i have a button for log out and when the screen navigate to the login page again the touch id verification show immediately but not in the proper way I think, can you help to get me now how to solve this? thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ltU.png)

Comment: check it out your touch id method when and where triggered in navigationController or viewController methods (like viewDidDisappear etc.) .

Comment: i work on flutter should i check it on xcode?